# matrix average of column pairs

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 100 X 10 matrix, where row is stock and column is the price at each month. I need to take the average price of each stock for every 2 months (in all 5 times for each stock according to the matrix given below). This should be done for all 100 stocks. How do I do this?

```
msft     20  30  40  50  60  70  35  76  46  90
good     30  45  24  45  56  67  56  65  55  66
aapl     60  46  56  32  43  54  55  57  67  56
yhoo     64  54  45  56  67  66  78  65  77  78
bac      45  43  54  45  62  54  57  67  78  54
jpm      34  35  36  56  54  43  58  69  54  67
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
(mat[, c(TRUE, FALSE)] + mat[, c(FALSE, TRUE)]) / 2
```

A generalization would be

```
n.by.n <- 2
j <- seq_len(ncol(mat))
j.list <- split(j, j %% n.by.n)
m.list <- lapply(j.list, function(j)mat[, j, drop = FALSE])
Reduce(`+`, m.list) / n.by.n
```

You can also use a matrix multiplication:

```
n.by.n <- 2
w <- matrix(0, ncol(mat), ncol(mat) / n.by.n)
w[(row(w) + 1) %/% n.by.n == col(w)] <- 1 / n.by.n
mat %*% w
```

Comment: the first solution looks cool so let me ask you this. Infact this is just a birds eye view of what I am trying to do . I have a 10000(stocks) by 1000(months). So its prices of 10000 stocks for 1000 months each. I need to find average  price of each stock for every 50 months just like we did for every two months in the example. TRUE,FALSE would get quickly out of hand or atleast for me .

Comment: perfect, look at how I generalized in my edit, just set `n.by.n` to `50`.

Comment: awesome , let me try that